# how to find a value from an array of objects based on another arrays with ids

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to filter name of genres for a movie based on ids. so if id matches I get that name out.

```
const genres = [
  { id: 28, name: "Action" },
  { id: 12, name: "Adventure" },
  { id: 16, name: "Animation" },
  { id: 35, name: "Comedy" },
  { id: 80, name: "Crime" },
  { id: 99, name: "Documentary" },
  { id: 18, name: "Drama" },
  { id: 10751, name: "Family" },
  { id: 14, name: "Fantasy" },
  { id: 36, name: "History" },
  { id: 27, name: "Horror" },
  { id: 10402, name: "Music" },
  { id: 9648, name: "Mystery" },
  { id: 10749, name: "Romance" },
  { id: 878, name: "Science Fiction" },
  { id: 10770, name: "TV Movie" },
  { id: 53, name: "Thriller" },
  { id: 10752, name: "War" },
  { id: 37, name: "Western" },
];

const genre_ids = [10752, 10770, 18, 12]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can filter `genres` using `genre_ids` and then map the specific values

```
function filterGenres(genres, ids) {
    return genres
        .filter((genre) => ids.indexOf(genre.id) != -1)
        .map((genre) => genre.name)
}
```

or alternatively use the `reduce` function

```
function filterGenres(genres, ids) {
    return genres.reduce((results, genre) => {
        if(ids.indexOf(genre.id) != -1) {
            results.push(genre.name);
        }
        return results;
    }, []);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The below may be one possible solution to achieve the desired objective.

**Code Snippet**

```js
const getNames = (ids, objects) => (
  ids.map(el => (
    objects.find(
      ({id}) => id === el
    )?.name
  ))
);

// below will be better in performance
// but the names returned will be ordered based on 'genres' array
//  objects.filter(({id}) => ids.some(el => el === id))
//  .map(({name}) => name)


const genres = [
  { id: 28, name: "Action" },
  { id: 12, name: "Adventure" },
  { id: 16, name: "Animation" },
  { id: 35, name: "Comedy" },
  { id: 80, name: "Crime" },
  { id: 99, name: "Documentary" },
  { id: 18, name: "Drama" },
  { id: 10751, name: "Family" },
  { id: 14, name: "Fantasy" },
  { id: 36, name: "History" },
  { id: 27, name: "Horror" },
  { id: 10402, name: "Music" },
  { id: 9648, name: "Mystery" },
  { id: 10749, name: "Romance" },
  { id: 878, name: "Science Fiction" },
  { id: 10770, name: "TV Movie" },
  { id: 53, name: "Thriller" },
  { id: 10752, name: "War" },
  { id: 37, name: "Western" },
];

const genre_ids = [10752, 10770, 18, 12];

console.log(getNames(genre_ids, genres));
```

**Explanation**

- A new method `getNames` is used to obtain the result
- For each id in `genre_ids` array
- Find if there is an entry in `genres` (by matching the `id` prop)
- If found, return the `name` prop from the matched `genres` element
- And the resulting array is returned (implicitly)

Commented-out method:

- Filter the `genres` and destructure to obtain just the `id`
- Check if the `id` is present in the `genre_ids` array
- If yes, use `.map` to destructure just the `name`
- And this resulting array of `name`s is returned (implicitly)

This method returns in a different order (based on the `genres` array).

Answer (score 1):

are you trying something like this -

```
let genre_names = new Array();
for(let i=0; i<genre_ids.length; i++) {
   var a = genres.find(x=>x.id == genre_ids[i]);
   if (!!a)
     genre_names.push(a.name);
}
console.log(genre_names);
```

resulting with [War,Tv Movies, drama, Adventure] ?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply achieve that by using [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) along with [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

```js
const genres = [
  { id: 28, name: "Action" },
  { id: 12, name: "Adventure" },
  { id: 16, name: "Animation" },
  { id: 35, name: "Comedy" },
  { id: 80, name: "Crime" },
  { id: 99, name: "Documentary" },
  { id: 18, name: "Drama" },
  { id: 10751, name: "Family" },
  { id: 14, name: "Fantasy" },
  { id: 36, name: "History" },
  { id: 27, name: "Horror" },
  { id: 10402, name: "Music" },
  { id: 9648, name: "Mystery" },
  { id: 10749, name: "Romance" },
  { id: 878, name: "Science Fiction" },
  { id: 10770, name: "TV Movie" },
  { id: 53, name: "Thriller" },
  { id: 10752, name: "War" },
  { id: 37, name: "Western" },
];

const genre_ids = [10752, 10770, 18, 12];

const res = genres.filter((obj) => {
    return genre_ids.indexOf(obj.id) !== -1
}).map((filteredObj) => filteredObj.name);

console.log(res);
```